# Set the default view frame different in Xcode 4.5.1 and ios 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

In story board, the view frame is set as `(0,64; 320,504)`.
When i write code in viewDidLoad method, the frame is set as (0 20; 320 460)

```
 NSLog(@"self.view: %@",self.view);
```

The out put is: `<UIView: 0x1e888c30; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e888c90>>`

Why does it show like this? Actually i thought the setting default view frame is same in everywhere.

I am not understand Please help me...

Comment: because of the autoresizing

Comment: are u using default UINavigationViewController?

Comment: I embedded navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autolayout was added-- if you wish to disable this:

-Right click on your storyboard and choose 'Show File Inspector'

-On the right menu that shows up, un-check 'Use Autolayout'

[image]

Things should be back to normal for you now